# Web URL conditional formatting more than first or last item?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I have two Power BI tables: 'Project Risk Names' and 'Project Risk URLs'.

Both are near identical - see below.

**Risk Names**

| Project | Risk 1 | Risk 2 | Risk 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Red | A | B | C |
| Blue | AA |  |  |
| Green | AAAA | BBB |  |

**Risk URLs**

| Project | Risk 1 | Risk 2 | Risk 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Red | https | https | https |
| Blue | https |  |  |
| Green | https | https |  |

Is there a way to hyperlink the Names values so they link to the relevant URL values? I've arranged both tables in Power Query.

Is there a lookup maybe which could find the specific URL based on Risk number and Project? I'm just guessing.

Thanks

Conditional formatting the Risk columns only seems to reference first or last item.

Comment: pleass be more clear what you are looking for by editing your questions with sample output